# Diferencia en la instanciación de un objecto

Tags: c++, poo, object

Estoy estudiando en C++, y manejando su sintaxis, y me topé con esta duda.
¿Cual es la diferencia entre definir objetos?

```
nameclass  nameobject; 
nameobject.namemétodo();
```

a esta otra:

```
nameclass *nameobject = new nameclass ();
nameobject->namemétodo();
```

Sé que se usa un puntero (*), y se trabaja dinámico. pero no sé en sí; que las diferencia.
En la primera instanciación para acceder a los métodos es con el punto (.).
y en la segunda es con (->). ¿Porque?

Aprecio y me ayuda cada respuesta, comentario o recomendación. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para este caso `nameclass  nameobject;` usted esta alamcenandolo en el [Stack](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pila_(inform%C3%A1tica)):

**STACK:**

En su programa cuando este se pone en macha, para cada hilo "thread" se le asigna una determinada cantidad de memoria limitada osea una cantidad limitada en el stack.

El Stack almacena la informacion que usted comenta las variables como otro tipo de informacion, como la direccion desde donde continuar al terminar una funcion recursiva ect. aparte las variables de estas funciones.

El stack es del tipo [LIFO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_in,_first_out) en este fracmento de memoria es donde se van apilando las funciones ejecutadas, las variables locales que usa cada funcion ect.

las variables almacenadas en el stack, son de rapido acceso estas variables solo se pueden acceder desde dentro del [scope](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81mbito_(programaci%C3%B3n)) en el que son declaradas.

las mismas son liberadas de forma automatica al salir del [scope](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81mbito_(programaci%C3%B3n)) o lo que es lo mismo en algunos casos al terminar el programa su ejecucion.

Por eso al tener un cantidad de memoria limitada no es recomendable almacenar grandes estructuras de datos en el stack, o como pueden ser arrays de grandes dimensiones pues esto podria dar lugar a desboramiento en la pila o lo que es lo mismo un Stack Overflow, asi que para prevenirnos de esto se crean en el Heap.

> Por ejemplo StackOverflow si se fija en la forma en la que aparece la
>   pregunta quizas entienda mejor LIFO del ingles Last In First Out,
>   «ultimo en entrar primero en salir» pero no lo tome como la ultima que
>   entra es la primera que se contesta, hablando de la pregunta, tomelo
>   como la ultima en entrar primera en mostrarse.

---

para su segundo caso `nameclass *nameobject = new nameclass ();` usted pide memoria en el [heap](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mont%C3%ADculo_(inform%C3%A1tica))

**HEAP:**

No tiene ninguna estructura de asignacion de espacios* y el tamaño es limitado por el tamaño de la memoria v. osea por la RAM y el espacio que se disponga de SWAP, es asignada en run_time y los bloques de memoria pueden o no ser continuos entre una declaracion y otra, pero no confundir esto con que un array no va a tener sus dimenciones continuas, pueden o no ser continuas en referente a una variable de otra, pero un array es una variable, espero explicarme y sus posiciones son continuas de ahy que se pueda hacer arimetica de punteros.

Como abra deducido el las operacion en el heap son mas lentas que en el stack
es muy posible que sepa de delete en c++ esto es usado para liberar la memoria que ha sido creada en el heap, mientras el programa esta en ejecucion, aunque se salga del scope de donde fue declarada la asignacion esta sigue estando presente en el heap y puede referecia a ellas, pero si usted pierde la referencia no creo que pueda referirse a ella de una manera sencilla, a su vez estas son liberadas cuando el programa termina en teoria por el SO.

El acceder de una forma u otra como cometa me imagino que es cosa de diseño del mismo lenguaje tanto usando `.` para una variables como o `->` para otras.

Comment: Agradecido por tomarte el tiempo de responder mi duda. gracias por enseñarme. :D

Answer (score 2):

Se usa el simbolo de -> simplemente porque asi es la sintaxis que define C++ para acceder al contenido  un puntero tanto de un objeto como de un struct, podriamos decir que es el azucar sintetico del clasico manejo de punteros.

Ejemplo si tu declaras

```
int main(){

    Persona* p1=new Persona;
    p1.comer();// Error de compilacion
    return 0;
}
```

Directamente no puedes acceder a sus atributos o funciones miembro porque al final de cuentas estas trabajando con un puntero. Si vemos este incoveniente desde el punto de vista clasico de los punteros tendriamos que especificarle a C++ que a travez del simbolo de * vamos a acceder al contenido donde apunta el objeto y ahora si con el simbolo punto accederiamos ha alguno de sus atributos o funciones miembro como se muestra a continuacion.

```
int main()
{
    Persona* p1=new Persona;
    (*p1).comer();

    return 0;
}
```

Son necesarios los parentesis porque le indican al compilador que estamos accediendo a los datos reales donde esta apuntando el objeto.

Como ves de que se puede acceder con el simbolo de punto se puede pero conlleva una problematica al momento de estar programando, resulta mas sencillo realizar la misma accion simplemente usando el simbolo de ->.

```
int main()
{
    Persona* p1=new Persona;
    p1->comer();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, gracias +1; no te doy el check de la respuesta porque no respondiste mi principal duda.

Comment: No hay problema pero ya con la respuesta de angel se complementa de mejor manera :)